# Convert part of rendered web page to standalone HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, wkhtmltopdf

I'm looking for a way to convert a piece of a rendered webpage to a standalone HTML file, specifically so I can convert to PDF using wkhtmltopdf.

The section has styles that are inherited from external and inline stylesheets, and styles and classes that are dynamically set via javascript depending on various circumstances. So I can't simply copy the stylesheets and raw HTML and dump it into a web page.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC on the server, but I would expect this to be done on the client with javascript if it's possible at all.

I can picture doing it by parsing through the HTML, and looping through every possible CSS and DOM value, then copying those to the output, but that's not really feasible...

Here's an idea of what I want to do:

### Original HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- this file contains the following:
         .field { color: #ff0; }
    ---------------------------------------->

    <style type="text/css">
        .section-header { font-weight: bold; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header-content">some stuff here</div>
    <div id="main-content">
        <div id="main-header" class="section-header">Here's my header</div>
        <div id="color-container">
            <label class="field">Color:</label>
            <select id="color">
                <option value="green">green</option>
                <option value="blue">blue</option>
                <option value="other">other</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="color-specify-container">
            <label class="field">Specify:</label>
            <input id="color-specify">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer-content">more stuff here</div>
    <script>
        jQuery("#color").change(function() {
            if (jQuery("#color").val() == "other") {
                jQuery("#color-specify-container").show();
            } else {
                jQuery("#color-specify-container").hide();
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And I want to convert only the `main-content` into PDF, so ideally I would want to generate the following HTML, with no dependencies on external libraries, no script to run, and the HTML with inline-styles to represent the actual styles as of right now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="main-content">
        <div id="main-header" style="font-weight: bold;">Here's my header</div>
        <div id="color-container">
            <label style="color: #ff0;">Color:</label>
            <select id="color">
                <option value="green">green</option>
                <option value="blue">blue</option>
                <option value="other">other</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <!-- 
            Assuming color is not "other" - if it is "other", then 
            the "display: none;" would not be here
        -->
        <div id="color-specify-container" style="display: none;">
            <label style="color; #ff0;">Specify:</label>
            <input id="color-specify">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to approach this would be to simply copy all of the HTML, and then delete everything that is a sibling of your target, except the target yourself.

Something like this:

```
const target = document.querySelector('#main-content');
const siblings = target.parentNode.querySelector('*:not(#main-content)');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(siblings, sibling => sibling.parentNode.removeChild(sibling));
```

Which can be shortened to just:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelector('#main-content').parentNode.querySelectorAll('*:not(#main-content)'), sibling => sibling.parentNode.removeChild(sibling));
```

If you open the page up in a new window and then run that, it'll delete everything but what you want to turn into a PDF.